# Let $\Phi = \{Rwt, Rzt, Rwt \wedge Rzt \rightarrow Rxt, y\equiv t\}$. Does $\mathcal{J}^{\Phi} \models Rxy$ hold?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Im working on a mathematical logic question but i'm a little stuck here. The question is the fallowing:

Let $\Phi = \{Rwt, Rzt, Rwt \wedge Rzt \rightarrow Rxt, y\equiv t\}$. Does $\mathcal{J}^{\Phi} \models Rxy$ hold?

I thought i might give an example of an interpretation such that it holds but i couldn't think of any good one. Does it even hold?? Who can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that from $\Phi$ you can infer $Rxy$: $Rwt,Rzt$ and $Rwt\land Rzt\to Rxt$ give you $Rxt$, and $y\equiv t$ then gives you $Rxy$.

Comment: I see but i have difficulties writing this in a formal way.

Comment: There I can’t really help, because I don’t know the details of the formalism that you’re using.

Comment: Would be enough to state that  $\mathcal{J}^{\Phi}\vdash\Phi$ and then use correctness to finish the prove?

Comment: What does $\mathcal{J}^\Phi$ mean in your notation?

Comment: I presume that $\mathcal J^\Phi$ meand an interpretation satisfying $\Phi$...

Comment: See Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum & Wolfgang Thomas, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA76) (2nd ed 1994), page 76.

Comment: That has to do with the definition used in Henkin's Theorem. It says: $\mathcal{J}^{\Phi} \models \phi$ iff $\Phi \vdash \phi$                              So i probably have to prove the right part.

Comment: It's hard to say what is the right answer without context... As said by Brian, $\Phi \vdash Rxy$; thus, by *soundness* : $\Phi \vDash Rxy$. This means that every interpretation satisfying all the formulae in $\Phi$ will also satisfy $Rxy$.